# K8s : nginx-ingress: SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:191CF08C:SSL routines:tls_parse_ctos_key_share:bad key share)

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, lets-encrypt, certificate-authority, nginx-ingress

As we found out that the nginx ingress as well as the cert-manager were outdated and not compatible with the Kubernetes version of 1.22 anymore.
I upgrade the two components: nginx-ingress from 0.26.1 to 1.5.1. and the cert-manager from version 0.12.0 to 1.5.

which lead to the cert-manager pods running

```
kubectl get pods -n cert-manager
NAME                                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
cert-manager-dfp85b9bd-ptk9l               1/1     Running   0          26h
cert-manager-cainjector-3d65bcdcfd-fktsz   1/1     Running   0          26h
cert-manager-webhook-c596f8c6c-8cx4x       1/1     Running   0          26h
```

AND

```
Kubectl get certificates -n default
NAME               READY   SECRET             AGE
alertmanager-tls   False   alertmanager-tls   1y12d
prometheus-tls     False   prometheus-tls     1y19d
```

and cmctl check api -n cert-manager returns: The cert-manager API is ready

Clean orphaned secrets
This deleted the automatically created self signed CA certificates of the cert-manager.After a restart the logs looked mainly clean.

Errors still existing:

```
cert-manager-cainjector: cert-manager/secret-for-certificate-mapper "msg"="unable to fetch certificate that owns the secret" "error"="Certificate.cert-manager.io "grafana-tls" not found"

nginx-ingress: SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:191CF08C:SSL routines:tls_parse_ctos_key_share:bad key share) while SSL handshaking, client
```